# Create submenus in modx revolution using wayfinder

Tags: php, css, modx, modx-revolution

I have Resources and I want to create submenu .

like i have resources

Home
About us 
Services
Blogs

Service1
service 2
service 3

Now i want to create submenu like

```
 <ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>SERVICES
 <ul>service1</ul>
 <ul>service2</ul
  <ul>service3</ul
 </li>
 <li>Blogs
   <ul>service1</ul>
    <ul>service2</ul
    <ul>service3</ul
 </li>
```

Means same link under 2 different menus but with different url , How can i do this using wayfinder in Modx revolution.

Currently service1 , 2  3  don't have parent resource.

Answer (score 1):

You could move Service 1, 2 and 3 under Services (as child docs). Then you could make three additional child resources under Blogs, and make each one of those a **symlink** to Service 1, 2, or 3.
[MODX Symlinks RTM](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/symlink)

Answer (score 0):

Wayfinder will do this out of the box. You need to create the structure in the site tree in MODX using a [Symlinks](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/symlink). Symlinks in MODX allow you to publish a Resource in another location and that Resource can have its own unique alias/URL.

Comment: Any example you have which will work in similar way ?